# Can I apply linear regression method for finding a and b of y=a(1/x)+b?

Tags: regression, linear

Simply I have a function which looks like this:
$$\lambda =\lambda_0 \cdot \exp(-T_0/T)\;,$$,
where $\lambda_0$ and $T_0$ are unknown constants.
By appplying to both sides ln() I get :
$$\ln(\lambda)=\ln(\lambda_0)-T_0(1/T)$$
It's of form  $y=b+a/x$.
The question is how can I apply linear regression formulae?
Maybe smart substitution will be enough ?

Comment: As long as $x$ is known, clearly also $1/x$ is known! This is just the usual linear regression with $1/x$ as precictor. Just calculate $z=1/x$ and use linear regression with $z$ as predictor. Or, if you are using R, use in the model formula $y \sim I(1/x)$.

Comment: @kjetil b halvorsen thanks for claryfying  the issue, what do you mean by R ?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen why not write in as an answer instead of comment ?

Comment: R is a statistical programming language / software package. See [here](https://www.r-project.org/). To apply a linear regression, you should include an additive error term in your model.

Comment: Your second model is *not* the same as the first: it posits a different pattern of errors.  Depending on what patterns are likely to hold for your data, you might need weighted least squares, a nonlinear regression, or even something else.

Comment: @SebastianPinocy Whether it makes sense to linearize and fit by least squares, or to fit the original equation by nonlinear least squares - or indeed whether some other approach is indicated, such as a generalized linear model - depends on the behavior of the error term (which you have ignored in your formulation). Numerous posts on site address this issue in a bit more detail (on a number of functions). See [Pitfalls in Fitting Nonlinear Models by Transforming to Linearity](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140706/pitfalls-in-fitting-nonlinear-models-by-transforming-to-linearity)...ctd

Comment: ctd... and  [Regression when response variable is a function](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218633/regression-when-response-variable-is-a-function) and [Need GLM ideas for nonlinear biochemical model](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164316/need-glm-ideas-for-nonlinear-biochemical-model). Also see some of the images and discussion [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105851/n-sigma-curves-for-a-non-linear-least-square-curve-fit) which may help clarify some issues.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if you take $\frac{1}{T}$ as predictor and $\ln(\lambda)$ as response, you just have a very usual linear regression problem.

Anyway, you should remember to check linear regression assumptions with the transformed variables.

Comment: Note that $T_0$ is unknown so you can't use it to make a predictor. (You may want to read whuber's comment under the question as well)